# citation with APA not working

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, apa6

I try to use the following code for citation but it is not working .

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
~\cite{Abuelyaman2008} ~\cite{Abuelyaman2008}

ssssssssss\citep{Agrawal2002}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{VSM_references}

\end{document}
```

I want to show author name and year if there is just one author but if there are three authors just show the
first author and et al.

This is one of the `.bib` entries:

```
@ARTICLE{Abuelyaman2008,
  author = {Eltayeb Salih Abuelyaman},
  title = {An Optimized Scheme for Vertical Partitioning of a Distributed Database},
  journal = {IJCSNS International Journal of Computer Science and Network Security},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {VOL.8 No.1},
  pages = {310-316},
  owner = {DELL2},
  timestamp = {2013.03.31}
}
```

And this is the other one:

```
@ARTICLE{Agrawal2002,
  author = {Sanjay Agrawal, Surajit Chaudhuri, Gautam Das},
  title = {DBXplorer: A System for Keyword-Based Search over Relational Databases},
  journal = {Data Engineering, 2002. Proceedings. 18th International Conference
    on. IEEE},
  year = {2002},
  owner = {Dell2},
  timestamp = {2013.03.30}
}
```

many thanks in advance
Ayham

Comment: Can you add an extract of the `.bib` file with the relevant entries?

Comment: Without an MWE it's difficult to see what the problem is, but perhaps [an example of mine](https://github.com/vermiculus/smcm-tex/blob/master/psyc/example.tex) (using BibLaTeX/`biber`) can help you find the error.

Comment: Why are you loading both apacite and cite? I'm not very familiar with either but I took a quick look and it seems apacite is an author-year citation style, whereas cite supports numerical citations.

Comment: I also remove the \usepackage{cite} but not working, i am uisng MikTex 2.9. Is there any help. How can i use APA format in Latex

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Ok many thanks for you, If you have any idea please guide me

Comment: Please if you can help me how can i do the citation , i will grateful for you, i wait that because i do not have time to submit my report

Comment: `author = {Sanjay Agrawal, Surajit Chaudhuri, Gautam Das},` is the wrong format, better use `author = {Sanjay Agrawal and Surajit Chaudhuri and Gautam Das},`; that is, use `First Last and First Last` or `Last, First and Last, First` etc. pp. as name format. Also `volume = {VOL.8 No.1},` does not seem to be right either, better use `volume = {8}, number = {1},`.

Comment: Furthermore you seem to use `natbib` command `\citep` although you use `apacite`. You might want to do something about that as well.

Comment: You also might like to be a bit more specific than *it is not working*.